# jquery cycles - affect the first and second tag within the div

Tags: jquery, parent-child, jquery-cycle, css

I am using cycles.js on a project that contains a few image slides like so:

```
<div id="cycles">
    <img src="1">
    <img src="2" style="display:none;">
    <img src="3" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

I gave all but the first img a 'display:none;' to fix the image stacking or flashing that sometimes occurs when the page hasn't fully loaded. Cycles then updates the images display attribute to be `display:block;` when it is needed, which is what I want.

But now when I wrap these images in `<a></a>` tags, these tags are affected by cycles but not the child tags inside these. The `<a></a>` tags inherit `display:block;` but the images retain  `display:none;` and don't display.

So how do I tell cycles to instead affect the second tag, not the first? I will just wrap each image slide in `<a href="#"></a>` to always make it true and consistent.

Help! Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried `<a href="#" style="display:none;"><img src="2"></a>` ?

Comment: @rrikesh hey, yeah I did try that but sadly it didn't do anything...

Comment: Well when I wrote this it was the middle of the night & It seems to only be an issue with ie7 which I don't really care about. But I am still curious how to affect the second tag and not the first. If anyone knows right off, let me know! Thanks